# JOLT remove the field from array

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I have to copy accounts to two level in the output. And from one level, i need to remove fullAccountNumber. But in my jolt spec, it is removing from both the level. Is it something i am missing with my remove spec in jolt?

I have below input

```json
{
  "applicant": {
    "accounts": [
      {
        "fullAccountNumber": "00000000006276110961",
        "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
        "accountType": "Checking"
      },
      {
        "fullAccountNumber": "00000000006276110961",
        "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
        "accountType": "Saving"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired output

```json
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "fullAccountNumber": "00000000006276110961",
      "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
      "accountType": "Checking"
    },
    {
      "fullAccountNumber": "00000000006276110961",
      "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
      "accountType": "Saving"
    }
  ],
  "ma-loan": {
    "accounts": [
      {
        "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
        "accountType": "Checking"
      },
      {
        "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
        "accountType": "Saving"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Jolt:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
       "applicant": {
          "accounts": ["accounts", "ma-loan.accounts"]
       }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
       "ma-loan": {
          "accounts": {
             "*": {
                  "fullAccountNumber": ""
               }
           }
       }
    }
  }
]
```

Current output: (removing fullAccountNumber from both level)

```json
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
      "accountType": "Checking"
    },
    {
      "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
      "accountType": "Saving"
    }
  ],
  "ma-loan": {
    "accounts": [
      {
        "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
        "accountType": "Checking"
      },
      {
        "maskedAccountNumber": "XXXXXX0961",
        "accountType": "Saving"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good sample of exceptional case for **remove** spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my above question. Here in my case *remove* operation won't work, i have to use *shift* operation on the outcome of first *shift* operation spec.

Solution 1:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "applicant": {
        "accounts": ["accounts", "ma-loan.accounts"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "ma-loan": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "accounts": {
          "*": {
            "fullAccountNumber": {
              "*": {
                "@(2,maskedAccountNumber)": "&5.&4.[&3].maskedAccountNumber",
                "@(2,accountType)": "&5.&4.[&3].accountType"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Solution 2:

Little improved solution, using single *shift* operation.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "applicant": {
        "accounts": {
          "*": {
            "fullAccountNumber": {
              "@": "accounts[].&"
            },
            "*": ["accounts[&1].&", "ma-loan.accounts[&1].&"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one more way to get this Output JSON. I just sharing this Spec as a piece of information. I hope this Spec will help someone.

#### Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "applicant": {
        "accounts": {
          "*": {
            "maskedAccountNumber": "Ma-loan.accounts[#2].maskedAccountNumber",
            "accountType": "Ma-loan.accounts[#2].accountType"
          },
          "@": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

#### Desired Output

```
{
  "accounts" : [ {
    "fullAccountNumber" : "00000000006276110961",
    "maskedAccountNumber" : "XXXXXX0961",
    "accountType" : "Checking"
  }, {
    "fullAccountNumber" : "00000000006276110961",
    "maskedAccountNumber" : "XXXXXX0961",
    "accountType" : "Saving"
  } ],
  "Ma-loan" : {
    "accounts" : [ {
      "maskedAccountNumber" : "XXXXXX0961",
      "accountType" : "Checking"
    }, {
      "maskedAccountNumber" : "XXXXXX0961",
      "accountType" : "Saving"
    } ]
  }
}
```